# Chrome for Android content access from external app

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile-browser

Is there any way to read page content (html source or DOM) from the active Chrome tab on Android devices?

Chrome for Android doesn't support extensions and there is no plans to implement Extension API on Chrome for Android in the nearest future (however, [Chrome for iOS now supports App Extensions](http://lifehacker.com/chrome-for-ios-adds-supports-for-extensions-1637664312)).

Some apps (for example, [LastPass](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lastpass.lpandroid)) can access web content inside web browser.

How can I get read access to the active web page? Are there any external Chrome APIs or something similar?

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do on the active tab?

Comment: I need to get text from some DOM node for the predefined web sites . Desktop browsers allow me to do it easily using extension, but on Chrome for Android and Opera Mobile extensions are not available. I'm looking for the alternative approach (native app or any other techniques).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be possible with [Android Accessibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html). I think the flag you need is [FLAG_REQUEST_ENHANCED_WEB_ACCESSIBILITY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html#FLAG_REQUEST_ENHANCED_WEB_ACCESSIBILITY), so you can inject JavaScript into the website.

As you can see [in this blog by lastbpass](https://blog.lastpass.com/en/2014/03/logging-into-android-apps-just-got.html/), they use the same approach. In the video at 0:53, you see the accessibility features they use.

Comment: They do, and it's an absolute terrible hack.

Comment: @Kinlan It indeed is. But as far as I know, there isn't a better solution to this problem.